# How to ignore inner static classes in Jacoco when using Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, jacoco

I know how to ignore classes defined in their own `.java` files, but not aware of how to ignore inner classes.

For example, I have class A with nested class B:

```java
class A {
    ...

    static class B {
        ...
    }
}
```

`jacocoTestReport` keeps checking the coverage when I want to ignore them in `jacoco.gradle` file with this syntax(learned from this post: [How to ignore inner/nested classes with JaCoCo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45814477/how-to-ignore-inner-nested-classes-with-jacoco)): (`setFrom` part is for later versions of Gradle, where `classDirectories = files()` is deprecated)

```
apply plugin: "jacoco"

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.3"
}

jacocoTestReport {
    afterEvaluate {
        classDirectories.setFrom(files(classDirectories.files.collect {
            fileTree(dir: it,
                    exclude: [
                            "com/example/xxx/*",
                            "com/example/xxx/A\$.*B*"
                    ])
        }))
    }
}
```

(`$` must be escaped, while in the post there is no need because he uses Maven when I use Gradle)

So, how can I ignore this inner class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last I found the answer with several trial-and-failure. Seems that the naming pattern follows *compiled Java classes naming convention*, as mentioned in the other post, and **will not require the `.` between the outer class and the inner class**. So, it should be like `A$B`. And, there may be some `.class` interfering(my guess), so I added `A$B*`(for other normal classes, last `*` is not needed).

So it becomes:

```
"com/example/xxx/A\$B*"
```

I hope there be some documentation about this pattern of exclusion. There is not, yet.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working for me, can you provide an example of how did you do it?

Comment: Hi, just use the pattern; maybe you have some simple repo for me to debug? Just a sample project in github would be nice. (And by simply creating a sample project may solve your problem, my personal exp)